# Decode JSON after POST in textarea

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am having an issue decoding a JSON string with PHP and I'm pretty sure I know what is causing it, but not sure how to fix it. I am putting an array that I convert to JSON into a hidden textarea and then posting that with other information to my PHP script.

Here is a sample of the JSON string that is being placed into the text area: I am using `$("#product_options").val(JSON.stringify(productOptions));` to place the JSON into the text box.

```
[{
   "optionID": "217",
   "optionValueID": ["3"]
}, {
   "optionID": "218",
   "optionValueID": ["5"]
}, {
   "optionID": "223",
   "optionValueID": ["8", "11"]
}, {
   "optionID": "208",
   "optionValue": ["test"]
}, {
   "optionID": "209",
   "optionValue": ["zxvsdfg"]
}, {
   "optionID": "219",
   "optionValue": ["2011-02-20"]
}, {
   "optionID": "221",
   "optionValue": ["22:25"]
}, {
   "optionID": "220",
   "optionValue": ["2011-02-20 22:25"]
}]
```

That decodes fine, but once I post it and read the value of the field in PHP using `$_POST['json_array']` it will not decode. Below is the entire post converted to JSON:

```
 {
    "full_name": "sdfg",
    "phone": "sdfg",
    "email": "sdfg",
    "notes": "sdgf",
    "product_id": "42",
    "product_options": "[{"
    optionID ":"
    217 ","
    optionValueID ":["
    3 "]},{"
    optionID ":"
    218 ","
    optionValueID ":["
    5 "]},{"
    optionID ":"
    223 ","
    optionValueID ":["
    8 ","
    11 "]},{"
    optionID ":"
    208 ","
    optionValue ":["
    test "]},{"
    optionID ":"
    209 ","
    optionValue ":["
    zxvsdfg "]},{"
    optionID ":"
    219 ","
    optionValue ":["
    2011 - 02 - 20 "]},{"
    optionID ":"
    221 ","
    optionValue ":["
    22: 25 "]},{"
    optionID ":"
    220 ","
    optionValue ":["
    2011 - 02 - 20 22: 25 "]}]"
}
```

EDIT:

This is the PHP code I am using to decode the JSON `$productOptions = json_decode($_POST['product_options']);`.

The error I receive is: `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` but that is because I am trying to loop through the array after its been converted from JSON.

Comment: *"it will not decode"* Please provide more information. What happens? Which error do you get?

Comment: The problem is that the last JSON you posted is [not valid](http://jsonlint.com). There are two `"` which break it. Until you post code on how you create the posted string, it is difficult to help you

Comment: looks like you have a JSON string being quoted inside the main JSON string, remove those quotes, it should work just fine

Comment: Please don't vote this down as this is a valid question. I have updated the question to include the error and the code I use to create and decode the JSON.  @Kingkero. I see that there are two singe quotes, but I have tried to trim those using trim("'",$_POST['product_options']) and I still get the error. I think that I am having an issue because I am posting the JSON into a textarea before submitting because it is valid prior to that.

Comment: @user3167249 How are you processing the data for your POST? I am guessing something like `serialize`. If that is the case, you cannot use `stringify()` but should add `productOptions` to the serialized data via JS directly

Comment: Look at my answer, you think that you are handling arrays, but you are trying to foreach on an object!

Comment: What is the value of `$productOptions`? What's the error that `json_decode` produces (if any, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php)?

Comment: @kingKero: I think you might have nailed it but I'm not sure how to solve it. I am using stringify to add the array to the text area (which I don't see a way around because I am passing it from one page to an iframe) and them I am using serialize when I post my data to the PHP script. Should I perhaps decode it in the iframe and then add it to the serialized data before I post?

Comment: @user3167249 sounds promising. Post the relevant code and we can help you modifiy it

Comment: Well after fighting with the code for 3 days I figured it out:  json_decode or eval cannot handle &quot;, which is how the quote was coming through in the post string but it displayed as a ' in the browser when I did a dump so was very hard to debug. So to solve I added the code: $_POST['product_options'] = str_replace('&quot;', '"', $_POST['product_options']); seems like a stupid PHP bug to me :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well after fighting with the code for 3 days I figured it out: json_decode or eval cannot handle " which is how the quote was coming through in the post string, but it displayed as a " in the browser when I did a variable dump so was very hard to debug. So to solve I added the code:

```
$_POST['product_options'] = str_replace('&quot;', '"', $_POST['product_options']);
```

seems like a stupid PHP bug to me :{

Comment: thanks, you brother. I stack with this 2days. I work on laravel use dd it gives me perfect feedback but when I try to echo this it gives me an error. Thanks a lot for your solution.

Answer (score 1):

A better way might be to use [`html_entity_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) to convert any html entity e.g:

```
$_POST['product_options'] = html_entity_decode($_POST['product_options']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Server and client sides are communicating with strings only.

Before posting the value you can call JSON.stringify() on the value to get a valid convertible string to be sent to the server

After you got your encoded json you should decode the encoded json with 
json_decode(). I that way you will get a PHP variable parsed from the string.
[link here for further information](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing, but since I think since I am putting it in a text box I am getting the string placed in single quotes and I can not get rid of them.

Comment: You migth want to consider not using that hidden input field.
giving a string as a value and get that value can scrue up the encoding.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you want to iterate the datastructure using `foreach` but what you really try is iterating over an object of the type `stdClass`, which you cannot since it does not implement `Iterator` class.

What you probably wanted to do in the first place is to convert the json to an `associative array` you do that by setting the second parameter of json_decode to true like so:
`json_decode($string, true)`

When you get errors like these, it can be useful to use `var_dump` or `print_r` to see what the variable really is, and what it contains.